# jQuery Button click on external webpage

Tags: jquery, dom, button, click, external

In order to test a website I'm working on, I need to write a small program with jQuery that would go through an extrenal page from a link, find a button from its class name and click on it.

Should I use the `click()` function?

How to get the DOM from an external webpage?

Answer (score 0):

`click()` is ok, but note that it only triggers the click action on the element, you actually wouldn't open another page.

If you want to open a page link pointing to then you should use

```
document.getElementById("linkId").click()
```

> How to getthe DOM from an extrenal webpage?

```
$.get('http://www.somehost.com', function( data ) {
    var htmlDoc = document.createElement( 'html' );
    htmlDoc.innerHTML = data;
    var resultBody = $("body", htmlDoc);
    //...
  }).fail(function() {
    //Loading failed
  });
}
```